# Is there a way to see all recent changes in an org

Tags: custom-object, administration, fields

Every time I have to move changes from my sandbox I wish there was a way to see all the new objects, fields I created or modified. This way I wouldn't forget a field or an object and that would save time having to re-bundle change sets.

Does anybody know a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ## [Monitor Setup Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=0)
>
> Setup Audit Trail tracks the recent setup changes that you and other admins have made to your org. Audit history is especially useful in orgs with multiple admins.
>
> To view the audit history, from Setup, enter View Setup Audit Trail in the Quick Find box, then select View Setup Audit Trail. To download your org’s full setup history for the past 180 days, click Download.

Comment: How come it only shows the 20 most recent changes? Is there a way to increase this number?

Comment: @Arthlete Read the second paragraph. You can either view the most recent changes or view the entire 180 day history.